# Pycharm Error: Expected type [Class Name] got 'str' instead

Tags: python, oop, typeerror

I am trying to read a CSV file into a list using a class.  The method runs correctly from within the file containing the method, but when I try to call the method in main.py using a class I get the following error: Expected type 'Readit', got 'str' instead.  Can you help me fix this code so it will run and explain why my code is wrong?  TIA.

This is my directory in Pycharm
Project->PythonTest->main.py, Stuff.py, test.csv

CSV file contents

test.csv file contents are a,b,c (line 1), 1,2,3 (line 2) and 4,5,6 (line 3)

The class in Stuff.py

```
class Readit:

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def csv_to_list(self):
        from csv import DictReader
        with open(self.file_name) as a_file:
            csv_reader = DictReader(a_file)
            temp = csv_reader
            print(temp)
```

The main.py file

```
from Stuff import Readit

file_name = "test.csv"
test_result = Readit.csv_to_list(file_name)
print(test_result)
```

When run in stuff csv_to_list gives this output
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}, {'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '6'}]

but I get the error below when I try to call the method in main.py

Expected type 'Readit', got 'str' instead

Comment: `Readit(file_name).csv_to_list()` might work better.  But it would be simpler to make this a standalone function instead of building a class around it for no particular reason.

Comment: Thanks, Samwise.  My intent is to perform a number of operations using this file.  That seemed like an appropriate use for a class?  I'm much more experienced with functional programing so still struggling with the OOP paradigm.

Comment: This isn't a good use case for defining your own class, because the only data in your class is a filename -- and there's a perfectly good existing class for that, which is `str`.  OOP doesn't mean that everything has to be its own class; the point of classes is usually to be reusable by other code as-is, and Python comes with a lot of very useful and flexible builtin classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sent the file_name to the function instead to the object and your function doesn't return any result. If you change your code a little bit:

```
import csv

class Readit:

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def csv_to_list(self):
        dict_list = []
        with open(self.file_name, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                dict_list.append(row)
        return dict_list
        
def main():
    file_name = "test.csv"
    obj = Readit(file_name).csv_to_list()
    print(obj)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}, {'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '6'}]
```